# Executing Oracle SQL Plus commands using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Is there any way to execute SQL Plus commands using JDBC oracle driver?
For example, oracle sql developer somehow use the JDBC to execute the sqlplus commands. How are they achieving this? is there any sample?

Regards,
Mayuran

Comment: No, that's not possible. As the name says "SQL Plus commands" can only be run in SQL\*Plus. Which commands exactly are you trying to run? Maybe there is a SQL equivalent.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  How sql developer does that? say for example set serveroutput on

Comment: I don't know the code of SQL Developer, but I would expect they simply implemented the equivalent to that statement in the Java (after all it's essentially only calling `dbms_output.enable`)